# jQuery Extracting html code from one spot and placing it in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, banner

I'm trying to manipulate a banner slider where it would take all the DOM rendered img tags from all the banners – except the first – and then load them back in one at a time in increments of a few seconds via a ***set Timeout***. I'm just trying to not bog down the page load because of the amount/size of the images.

My issue is that I cannot seem to get the ***if*** statement to bypass the first instance of the img tag and remove the others. Its all or none, so I think the ***img[0]*** may not be correct. I have also tried ***.first()*** with no luck, and also css' ***first-child*** & ***nth-child(1)***. I also tried creating a new array with the img tag html and then continue on...but that proved **No Good** either.

Any ideas how I can get this going? And if y'all have a better approach, I'm open for suggestions.

Thank you.

```js
var img = $('div > img');
$.each(img, function(i) {
  if ( !img[0] ) {
     img.remove();
     setTimeout(function(){
        $('.main').append(img);
     }, i * 2000);
  }

});
```

```css
.main {
   width: 200px;
   height: 80px;
   padding: 10px;
   overflow: visible;
   border: 2px solid red;
}
.div1,
.div2,
.div3 {
   width: 200px;
   height: 80px;
   background: #ccc;
   float: left;
   position: absolute;
}
.div2 {left:232px;}
.div3 {left:437px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
       
   <div class='div1'>
      <img src="#" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class='div2'>
      <img src="#" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class='div3'>
      <img src="#" alt="">
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're talking about lazy loading. Have a look at [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes), they've got a demo link.

Comment: Yes, something like it...but unfortunately this is for an already built-in banner system in a CMS. I cannot include another third party library. I have to work with what I have in the CMS.

Comment: Perhaps try Googling lazy loading vanilla js, but I tried that and didn't find anything. If you can't load an external library via CDN, I don't know. Sorry.